# Packagekit blocking everthing else

Tags: 20.04, mysql, webmin

Well I don't know if it's blocking EVERYTHING else, but it's blocking a lot.

I have an AWS instance running Ubuntu 20.04.  This is a web server that hosts dozens of php/mysql sites that are "archives" or old versions of a web site that gets completely revised annually. From time to time everything goes dead... apache, mysql, even the webmin system I used to manage it.  Even much of the webmin stats collection stops.

It happened again last night, for about 2 minutes. I did find one stat still being collected, "services", and it shows packagekit spiking that same time other stat collection goes dead.

What gives?

[image: The spike at 006:00 on Tuesday coincides with the server outage]

Comment: One of the first things I check when trying to solve this sort of issue is the `/var/log/syslog` file. See if there is a scheduled job or service that is putting the server under excessive load. If you have statistics for IO load over time, that would also be a good indicator of systems that need attention as a saturated IO system will make it impossible for any running service to access or record data 

Comment: Thank you.  Now I need to learn what a healthy syslog looks like.  Lots of stuff in there. For example, this repeated every few seconds:
systemd[1]: Started System monitoring daemon.
mon[568151]: cf error: unknown syntax [authtype = userfile], line 64
mon[568151]: cf error: unknown syntax [authtype = userfile], line 64
systemd[1]: mon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
systemd[1]: mon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: mon.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 328549.
systemd[1]: Stopped System monitoring daemon.